# IE9 Browser issue with Bootstrap and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, solr

We are running a SOLR banana application that is built using Bootstrap and angular framework.

The application works fine with any modern browsers but I have some problem with IE9. I have 3 d3 graphs and html table within my application.

Here is my HTML page that is being rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I don't see the d3 graphs being rendered. The "browser mode" is set to unknown even when I force it to IE=edge.

Another strange thing his I see some `<style>` tag between my `<head>` and `<meta>` tag rendered automatically.

Not sure how that gets rendered.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's some kind of "HTML5 shiv" to correctly render elements that aren't known to old IE. Shouldn't be a problem, but what's the full code inside?

Comment: Full code inside? You want the meta tags or the style tags?..I believe the style tags between head and meta ignores the meta tags info.

Comment: The `<style>` tag. But aside from that, do you get any errors in the console?